# Prevent frame to go under the taskbar

Tags: c++, windows-7, wxwidgets

I have frame with custom bacground image and without borders, capture and control like close, minimize and maximize. In code I capture dragging event and move frame according to new mouse coordinates.

And I have problem, when I drag frame under the taskbar. This move not preventing anyhow (but standard windows I cant drop into unreachable area under taskbar, but my frame I can). Is there the way to catch this situation and prevent cursor movin down under taskbar? BTW can i make sticking to screen edges?

Here is the code for dragging:

```
void MainFrame::OnMouseLeftDown(wxMouseEvent& event)
{
    CaptureMouse();

    wxPoint pos = ClientToScreen(event.GetPosition());
    wxPoint origin = GetPosition();

    int dx = pos.x - origin.x;
    int dy = pos.y - origin.y;

    m_PosDelta = wxPoint(dx, dy);
}

void MainFrame::OnMouseMove(wxMouseEvent& event)
{
    if (event.Dragging() && event.LeftIsDown())
    {
        wxPoint pos = ClientToScreen(event.GetPosition());
        Move(wxPoint(pos.x - m_PosDelta.x, pos.y - m_PosDelta.y));
    }
}

void MainFrame::OnMouseLeftUp(wxMouseEvent& event)
{
    if (HasCapture()) ReleaseMouse();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to use `wxDisplay::GetFromPoint()` to determine the display you are currently on and then `wxDisplay::GetClientArea()` to find the boundaries for the window position on it and adjust it so that the window fits in the client area entirely.

Comment: Thanks! But i want to get movement of my frame like standard window - I can move window left and rigth without restrictions (my frame works like this by default) and i cannot move CURSOR above taskbar on the bottom of the screen

Comment: Or wherever taskbar is (top or left or rigth)

Comment: Because the window manager (shell) already does this internally. As you don't use its resizing code, you have to do it on your own, there is no magic here.

Comment: I'm totally confused. Can you improve my code from the original post to achieve native window behavior? I will really thankful, because I cant find examples of working code for this, and cant do it by my own